# Getting Last Active URL Prior to Logout in Angular 2 App

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, routes, synchronous

In my Angular 2 app I am trying to store the last active URL `prior` to a user logging out, so that that url can be re-loaded after the user re-logs in. However, this is proving problematic. Consider this logout function from my authenticationService:

```
logout()
{
    let lastUrl = this.getActiveUrl();
    console.log('Url before logout: ', lastUrl);

    this.apiService.logout();
}
```

Notice here that "lastUrl", which calls `this.getActiveUrl()`, which looks like this:

```
getActiveUrl()
{
    let activeUrl = this.router.routerState.snapshot['url'];
    console.log('activeUrl: ', activeUrl);
    return activeUrl;
}
```

...appears BEFORE `this.apiService.logout()`. But, nevertheless, what gets printed to the console for "lastUrl" is "/login". But that's the URL where I end up immediately *after* logging out.

So, help me understand this:

If this is synchronous, why doesn't the correct URL print here? What am I missing? And how can I get the active url immediately *prior* to logout firing and re-directing to '/login'?

EDIT: After a commenter's suggestion, I tried assigning to localStorage instead of a local variable, like so:

```
logout()
{
    localStorage.setItem('returnUrl', JSON.stringify(this.router.routerState.snapshot['url']));

    this.apiService.logout();
}
```

But when I dig that value out with `localStorage.returnUrl`, I still get "/login".

Comment: If you put let lastUrl = this.router.routerState.snapshot['url']; it works?

Comment: you can use `Router` instead of `ActivatedRoute` and get the url using `this.route.url`

Comment: See what I ended up doing below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, many thanks to @Sam for the localStorage suggestion. I should have thought of that. So, in the end, all I needed to do was make use of RouterStateSnapshot from my `canActivate()` function in my AuthGuardService, and save that value to localStorage. Then I just retrieve that value to plugin in on re-authentication and re-login:

```
    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot)
    {

        // Get route content id
        let contentId = Object.getPropertyValueAtPath(route, 'data.contentId');

        // Store last active URL prior to logout, so user can be redirected on re-login
        localStorage.setItem('returnUrl', JSON.stringify(state.url));

        // DO OTHER STUFF...

    }
```

In my login component I just get that value to pass in...

```
login(response)
{
    this.loading = true;

    this.authenticationService.login(this.model.username, this.model.password, function (results)
    {
        if (results.data && results.ok === true)
        {
            this.returnUrl = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('returnUrl'));
            this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl || '/']);
            console.log('ReturnURL Value is: ', this.returnUrl);
            this.reset();
        }
        else
        {
            this.alertService.error(null, response);
            this.loading = false;
        }

    }.bind(this));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is happening synchronously. However, you are logging  an object pointer. By the time you look at the object in the console, it has changed because the route has changed. 
I suggest using local storage to store the router snapshot. This will not have the same pointer issue that you see in the console.

Comment: Ah, okay, interesting. I will give it a try, thanks. I didn't realize assigning to a local variable would cause that issue.

Comment: No luck. Same result. I will post above what I tried.

Comment: Oh right. Maybe I am mistaken. I will delete if this doesn't work, but have you tried angular.copy to create a copy of the variable.

Comment: Actually, have an idea. Going to try saving to localStorage from my authGuard file. This may work...

Comment: Great. There are guards when you navigate away as well as when you navigate to a page. I assume you are navigating away